# asymptotic approximation of Fresnel integrals with complex argument

Tags: asymptotics, fresnel-integrals

It turns out that SciPy's Fresnel values are wrong for complex arguments and large enough absolute value. I'm trying to fix that.

The implementation is based on Zhang/Jin, *Computation of special functions*, which in turn is based on Abramowitz/Stegun, *Handbook of Mathematical Functions*. There we find for the Fresnel S integral (7.3.10)
$$
S(z) = \frac{1}{2} - f(z) \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} z^2\right) - g(z) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} z^2\right)
$$
for all $z$ with the auxiliary functions (7.3.5), (7.3.6)
$$
\begin{split}
f(z) &= \left[\frac{1}{2} - S(z) \right] \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} z^2\right) - \left[\frac{1}{2} - C(z) \right] \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} z^2\right),\\
g(z) &= \left[\frac{1}{2} - C(z) \right] \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} z^2\right) + \left[\frac{1}{2} - S(z) \right] \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} z^2\right).
\end{split}
$$

Computation of $S$ for large values is done via the asymptotic expansion of $f$ (7.3.27)
$$
\DeclareMathOperator\arg{arg}
\pi z f(z)\sim 1 + \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^m \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot\cdots \cdot (4m-1)}{(\pi z^2)^{2m}}, \quad z\to\infty, |\arg(z)|<\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
This is where I have problems understanding the approximation.
Consider $f(iz)$; for the asymptotic $f_a$, we have $f_a(iz) = -if_a(z)$. However no such thing is true for $f$ itself. Numerical computation via the representations
$$
\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}
\begin{split}
S(z) &= \frac{1 + i}{4} \left[\erf\left(\frac{1 + i}{2} \sqrt{\pi} z\right) - i  \erf\left(\frac{1 - i}{2} \sqrt{\pi} z\right)\right]\\
C(z) &= \frac{1 - i}{4} \left[\erf\left(\frac{1 + i}{2} \sqrt{\pi} z\right) + i \erf\left(\frac{1 - i}{2} \sqrt{\pi} z\right)\right]
\end{split}
$$
shows that the approximation incorrect for everything off of the real axis, but the issue here could be numerical instability in the $\erf$ represenation too.

My current guess is that the above infinite sum is valid only in the area $|\arg{z}|<\pi/4$, which would already change how we compute the Fresnel integral values significantly.

To finish things off, here's a cplot of $f$ (for smaller $|z|$):

[image]

Comment: The signum function is not defined for complex x.  I'd try the expansions in the Digital Library of Mathematical Functions 7.12.2-7.

Comment: I've checked those, and it seems to me that the asymptotic expansion of the auxiliary function is indeed wrong for values away from the real axis. I've created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/nschloe/e06c57bcfc5e9f592a180c1c54c358d7).

Comment: I only glanced at the code, so what I say may not be true in actuality.  It seems you are testing the algorithm with somewhat small values of |z|, like around 5 or so.  The formulas you tried, and the complex analog I pointed you to, are asymptotic.  For a moderate |z|, you will need a sophisticated way to truncate the infinite series and may need dozens of terms.  You might be able to use acceleration methods  to converge on an answer.  For |z| small enough, the asymptotic expansion is meaningless.  In that case it is better to use a error function representation that takes complex arguments.

Comment: Matlab, which is close to SciPy (I think) has a user-submitted Fresnel integral with complex argument z.  I have not downloaded or tested it. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18021-fresnel-integral

Comment: Thanks @skbmoore for the comments. I tested values around 5 since 4.5 is the point where algorithms (such as the one in scipy) switch to the asymptotic mode. Results don't get any better for larger $|z|$. I really do think the expansion is not valid for the argument range given on NIST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will consider the function $\operatorname{f}(z)$, the treatment of $\operatorname{g}(z)$ is analogous. By http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.12.ii, we have
$$
\operatorname{f}(z) = \frac{1}{{\pi z}}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^{N - 1} {( - 1)^m \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)_{2m} \frac{1}{{(\pi z^2 /2)^{2m} }}}  + R_N^{(\operatorname{f})} (z)
$$
where
\begin{align*}
R_N^{(\operatorname{f})} (z) & = \frac{{( - 1)^N }}{{\pi \sqrt 2 }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - \pi z^2 t/2} t^{2N - 1/2} }}{{1 + t^2 }}dt} \\ & = \frac{1}{{\pi z}}( - 1)^N \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)_{2N} \frac{1}{{(\pi z^2 /2)^{2N} }}\frac{1}{{\Gamma \left( {2N + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - s} s^{2N - 1/2} }}{{1 + s^2 /(\pi z^2 /2)^2 }}ds} 
\\ &
 = \frac{1}{{\pi z}}( - 1)^N \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)_{2N} \frac{1}{{(\pi z^2 /2)^{2N} }}\Pi _{2N + 1/2} (\pi z^2 /2),
\end{align*}
provided that $|\arg z|<\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $N\geq 0$. Here $\Pi_p(w)$ denotes one of Dingle's *basic terminant*s:
$$
\Pi _p (w) = \frac{1}{{\Gamma (p)}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - s} s^{p - 1} }}{{1 + (s/w)^2 }}ds} 
$$
for $|\arg w|<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and by analytic continuation elswhere. Using the expression for $R_N^{(\operatorname{f})} (z)$ in terms of this terminant, we can extend $R_N^{(\operatorname{f})} (z)$ to the universal covering of $\mathbb C \setminus \left\{ 0\right\}$. Now employing the estimates for the basic terminant established in https://doi.org/10.1007/s10440-017-0099-0, we obtain the bound
\begin{align*}
\left| {R_N^{(\operatorname{f})} (z)} \right| \le &\; \left| {\frac{1}{{\pi z}}( - 1)^N \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)_{2N} \frac{1}{{(\pi z^2 /2)^{2N} }}} \right| \\  & \times \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } \; \left|\arg z\right| \leq \frac{\pi}{8}, \\ \min\!\Big(\left|\csc ( 4\arg z)\right|,1 + \cfrac{1}{2}\chi(2N+1/2)\Big) & \text{ if } \; \frac{\pi}{8} < \left|\arg z\right| \leq \frac{\pi}{4}, \\ \cfrac{\sqrt {2\pi (2N + 1/2)} }{2\left| {\sin (2\arg z)} \right|^{2N+1/2} } + 1 + \cfrac{1}{2}\chi (2N +1/2) & \text{ if } \; \frac{\pi}{4} < \left|\arg z\right| < \frac{\pi}{2}. \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Here $\chi(p) =\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(p/2+1)/\Gamma(p/2+1/2)$ for $p>0$. It is seen that the asymptotic expansion of $\operatorname{f}(z)$ is valid in every closed sub-sector of $|\arg z|<\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the sense of Poincaré. The *Stokes lines* are $\arg z =\pm \frac{\pi}{4}$ where terms are swiched on that remain exponentially small compared to any negative power of $z$ as long as we stay away from the rays $\arg z =\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ (the *anti-Stokes lines*).

To obtain a better result and reveal the exponentially small terms, we can use the functional equation
$$
\Pi _p (w) =  \pm \pi i\frac{{e^{ \mp \frac{\pi }{2}ip} }}{{\Gamma (p)}}w^p e^{ \pm iw}  + \Pi _p (we^{ \mp \pi i} )
$$
where $p>0$ and $w$ is any element of the universal covering of $\mathbb C \setminus \left\{ 0\right\}$ (the Riemann surface of the logarithm). With this functional equation, we find, after some algebra,
$$
R_N^{(\operatorname{f})} (ze^{ \mp \frac{\pi }{2}i} ) =  \pm iR_N^{(\operatorname{f})} (z) + \frac{{1 \mp i}}{2}e^{ \pm \frac{\pi }{2}iz^2 } .
$$
This result is valid for all $N\geq 0$ and $z$ on the universal covering of $\mathbb C \setminus \left\{ 0\right\}$. You can see that if we omit the second term (which is exponentially small when $
 0 < \pm \arg z < \frac{\pi}{2}$) then, with $N=0$, we get the false result
$$
\operatorname{f}(ze^{ \mp \frac{\pi }{2}i} ) =  \pm i\operatorname{f}(z).
$$
See also http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.4.

In summary, use
$$
\operatorname{f}(z) \sim \frac{1}{{\pi z}}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^m \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)_{2m} \frac{1}{{(\pi z^2 /2)^{2m} }}} 
$$
when $\left| {\arg z} \right| \le \frac{\pi }{4}$, and use
$$
\operatorname{f}(z) \sim  \frac{{1 \pm i}}{2}e^{ \pm \frac{\pi }{2}iz^2 }  + \frac{1}{{\pi z}}\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^m \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)_{2m} \frac{1}{{(\pi z^2 /2)^{2m} }}} 
$$
when $\frac{\pi }{4} <  \pm \arg z \le \frac{{3\pi }}{4}$. Of couse by relaying on the symmetry relation http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.4.E8, we can assume $|\arg z|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the extensive write-up! The error bounds are very instructive and indeed say "stay away from the imaginary axis". I've just PR'ed a fix in SciPy, using the symmetry relations in S and C themselves, which turned out to be somewhat easier.